# How to open a .lwp file on a Mac?

Tags: file-conversion, ms-office, document-management

I need to fill in a form that was sent to me in .lwp format... So far:

- The App Store couldn't find any compatible apps;
- I found out it's a [Lotus WordPro](http://filext.com/file-extension/lwp) document;
- By using Word's [Recover text from any file](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/1/helproom/227295/convert-lwp-file-to-doc/), the content is all messed up;
- I don't have access to a PC to use [WordPort](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/554314) nor [Kvlotus.exe](http://filext.com/info/showthread.php?p=6113);
- I read the solution is to install [IBM Lotus Symphony](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-apps-games/152702-lwp-doc.html#post848980)...

...but before I [download a 250MB+ package](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/home) and install it for a one time thing, did anyone here face the same problem just to come to a more elegant solution to convert this file to a more useful format?

---

*Later edit:* installing **Symphony doesn't support it** either:

[image: Open .lwp file in IBM Lotus Symphony for Mac]

So my question remains: how do you use a **.lwp** file on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used www.fileminx.com to convert my LWP file into MSWord.

Comment: www.fileminx.com worked beautifully

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice version 3.3 and later has a Lotus WordPro import filter (see screenshot here: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/3-3-new-features-and-fixes/). You can download LibreOffice here:

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/